# how do i show 404 error page without showing the error page's url?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

when my users type a non-existent page such as

```
www.example.com\wrongurl.html
```

I want users to see 404 error page. But the URL should not change.

I have tried the following but doesn't work.

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.example.com/404.html

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule 404/ http://www.example/404.html [NC]
```

How can i do this?

Comment: You need not specify the domain. `ErrorDocument 404 /404.html` is good enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following rules :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^ /404.html [L,NC]
```

This internally redirects a request for non-existing file/directory to 404.html page.

Comment: I just realised a problem. when i click on any of the links in my site, it shows the 404 page. How do i fix this?

Comment: I believe this is happening because of other rules in your htaccess because The RewriteRule in my answer does not interfare with any existing files and dirs